# Hibernate returning string with bad encoding

Tags: java, hibernate, character-encoding

When I fetch an entity in my database with Hibernate, the returned string is poorly encoded. The database is Oracle 11g.

Example : 
`2015.2 Ajout d’un point de contrôle`

is returned as :

`2015.2 Ajout d\u0092un point de contrôle`

I tried a few settings in hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf-16</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf-16</property>
```

But without success.

Here are the database settings :

`NLS_CHARACTERSET   WE8MSWIN1252`
`NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16`

The row containing the data is described as VARCHAR2(255 Bytes)

What can I do to return a correctly encoded string to my entity ?

Comment: Why use "smart quotes" instead of regular quotes?

Comment: This data is a file name created by another user, that is referenced in my system. I have no power to enforce a filename policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the data was bad before it was inserted into the database. `\u0092` isn't a valid code point in Unicode, but it's present in [Windows-1252 (CP1252)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). That suggests someone inserted data with Windows encoding into the database instead of converting the characters to proper Unicode, first.

A common source for this kind of problem is when you read text files without specifying an encoding or when you rely on the platform default charset when encoding/decoding bytes into Strings.

Comment: Not every possible combination of a 24bit number corresponds to a valid code point in Unicode in the sense that there are gaps in the code pages. The code page `\u0080` to `\u00ff` only lists control characters for the code points `\u0080` to `\u00a0`. So in Unicode, `\u0092` means "PU2" which isn't printable. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm